# How to get array length in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I need to show table, if array have elements, and some another block, if array is empty? I have only for-each now. My array has "items" name.

```
<some table header code...>
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">
    <some row code...>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want another variant, something like this, but in XSL style:

```
<xsl:if list is empty>
    <block> There is no elements!!! </block>
<xsl:else>
    <table code>
</xsl:if>
```

How i can do it? I need if for FOP (pdf generator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="items/item">
       <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <some row code...>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
       <block>  ... </block>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But this would be a better approach:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="items[not(item)] | items/item" />

...

<xsl:template match="items">
   <block> ... </block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
   <!-- Row code -->
</xsl:template>
```